# Dynamic component loading using Parent Class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to create a generic code for dynamic component loading.
I have implemented parent child relationship. In it, child is overriding parent and will be used to dynamically load components.Below is the link I followed -

[dynamic component loading](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component)

I made changes in it and now it looks something like below link -

[Updated with my changes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component-c6vexd)

Somehow it is not working and doesn't load changes.
What am i missing here.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: i have updated the above url. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component-c6vexd

Comment: In module.ts, i am trying to replace original component passed in DynamicModule.withComponents([Child1,Child2] with DynamicModule.withComponents([ParentClass,ParentClass]. and that is causing this issue. looking for a way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by adding below lines in my module.ts -

```
 entryComponents: [
    Child1, Child2
]
```